# How to install Beautiful Soup 4 without *any* assumptions

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip

I need to install Beautiful Soup 4, but every tutorial or list of instructions seems to assume I know more than I do. I am here after a number of unsuccessful attempts and at this point I am afraid of damaging something internally.

Apparently I need something called `pip`. I have Python 3.8, so everyone says I should have `pip`. Great. I have found no less than 14 different ways to check if I actually have pip and am using it. They all say to type something. One of them said to type `pip --version`. We are already assuming too much. Where do I type it? IDLE? The Cmd prompt? The Python shell? What folder do I need to be in? Etc Etc. I need someone to assume I am a complete beginner.

Then, how do I use it to install bs4? Again, I am supposed to type things, but no one says where. One person said to go to the folder where python is installed in the command line. So, I did, and surprise surprise, pip is not "valid syntax". How can I proceed with this?

Comment: you run it from the command line ... the command line never cares about syntax so you would not get an error like you described unless you were not at the command line ... maybe you were in python (but even then typing pip would not be a syntax error... which makes me wonder where you typed pip --version

Comment: @DYZ I am not a programmer. I am taking a very beginner's course and the instructor told me to do this. The answers don't seem to exist because everyone seems to assume everyone else should know them.

Comment: which OS are you on? I always have to install `apt install python3-pip` when using a fresh debian linux install

Comment: @Tenacious B I am using Windows 10

Comment: @DYZ Yes, I have been doing a lot of Googling. You may assume I am foolish or stupid, and perhaps I am, but that would make it all more nice of you to help me out.

Comment: open your command prompt and type in `pip install beautifulsoup4`

Comment: @TenaciousB I got 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file, as I have many times before. (Not trying to be snarky, just pointing out to folks such as DYZ that I have been at it for awhile).

Comment: what if you type `python` in the command prompt?

Comment: @TenaciousB Thank you for attempting to help. I appreciate it very much. I get 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. (I have been using it for quite some time to do my coursework on this same machine so... ?)

Comment: as much as I hate to say it, try downloading python from the windows store, it will install automatically and should add to your PATH

Comment: @Tenacious B, I got ```python``` to work by navigating to a specific folder, but ```pip install beautifulsoup4``` still returns the same error

Comment: is `pip.exe` in `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts` you may as well just reinstall python

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213744/discussion-between-the-count-and-tenacious-b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like python and pip were not added to your environment variable Path when it was installed/updated (this has happened to me when updating).

Here is a quick guide on [how to add programs to your Path](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/).

You may have to modify these paths for your python version and username but add these to your path: `C:\Users\Greg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\scripts\` and 
`C:\Users\Greg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\`

log out and back in and the python and pip commands should work from anywhere in the command line

Answer (score 0):

With a little help from the kind user Tenacious B, I have solved my problem, I think. In the command prompt, I needed to type

`cd C:\Users\%userprofilenamegoeshere%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\scripts`

No source that I found in my initial search included that last bit: `\scripts`. From here, the common suggestion of `pip install beautifulsoup4` seems to have worked.